# Model Serving Databricks Status Failed

Tags: model, databricks, mlflow, serving

I'm trying to enable serving for my model but I keep getting *Pending* into *Failed* Status.
Here are the model event logs.

```
2022-11-15 15:43:13ENDPOINT_UPDATED

Failed to create model 3 times2022-11-15 15:43:03ENDPOINT_UPDATED

Failed to create cluster 3 times. Message: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Custom spark images are not allowed for your workspace2022-11-15 15:42:53ENDPOINT_UPDATED

Failed to create cluster 2 times. Message: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Custom spark images are not allowed for your workspace2022-11-15 15:42:43ENDPOINT_UPDATED
```

This used to work fine months ago but for some reason, I am not able to get a ready cluster for it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error message wasn't very helpful. I asked Databricks support and we have an enhanced security package, which doesn't support real time inference endpoints.